# Node.js & Socket.io - Messages from cmd sending multiple times

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets

I made a function so you can send messages to the chat from CMD, broadcasting it as server. But, I ran into a problem. Each time I reload the page, the message gets sent that many times. So if I reload the page 5 times, the server message gets sent 6 times. (counting the first load)

Here's an example:
[image]
[image]
[image]

Below is a branch of the complete code. How would I go about fixing this?

<strike>https://github.com/Crypting/chat/tree/server_messages</strike>

EDIT: Problem was solved, so the branch will no longer show the issue. I have uploaded the code to gist if anyone happens to run into this problem - https://gist.github.com/Crypting/dc5167c8ca3b18950b39

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, taken from your app.js:

```
io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    ...
    var stdin = process.stdin, stdout = process.stdout;

    stdin.resume();
    stdin.on('data', function(data) {
        ...
    });
});
```

That literally means: Every time there is someone connecting, you add another listener to stdin.
Instead move it outside of the connection handler:

```
io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    ...
});

var stdin = process.stdin, stdout = process.stdout;

stdin.resume();
stdin.on('data', function(data) {
    ...
});
```

Comment: Ohh, why didn't I notice this... Thanks :)